# How do you design a query conceptually?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

(If this is in the wrong location, please let me know and I'll move it, it is programming related, but I'm looking for a general framework.)

I'm looking to establish best practices for my query design by establishing a framework, or a design process I can follow when coming up with a new query.

I find myself developing queries and then getting confused about how to get the results I need.

- Do you have a design process or guidelines when you need to create a new query?
- Do you draw it out on paper?
- Are there certain questions you ask yourself when coming up with a
  design?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: How should I prevent SQL injection attacks, defend against "bad" data, invest in premature optimization, use transactions appropriately, why isn't this <term of endearment/> database normalized, ... ?

Comment: I think there can be so much different (and correct) answers to your questions that you'll be lost if you read them all. Experience is the biggest thing you need and the most difficult to acquire. I can't explain how I design a query conceptually, because I just _see_ the data, from their source to the result. But I remember that I asked myself the same questions as you 10-15 years ago. I have not changed my approach or my methodology, just the experience brought me new possibilities. There is at least one thing you need to achieve: to know the standard ANSI SQL by heart. I wish you good luck.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasG.  I'm glad to know the more experience I get, the better I'll be able to 'see the data'.  Struggling a little with that now, to see how the data interrelates.  Peter Campbell's questions and design comment is very helpful, so I'll probably try to develop my own as I go, but having questions and design ideas from Pros really help.

Comment: If the answer below has answered your question, could you mark it is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with any type of programming your code should be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so design out the repeating parts and use stored procedures, views and functions to do these parts.

Also important in SQL is readability - at some point some poor sod (maybe a future you) is going to have to read your code and try and make sense of it. So try and avoid long queries, break them down using temp tables or views.

*Just a few quick thoughts...*

**Design Process Questions**

- What tables do I need to query?
- What indexes and relationships do these tables have? - this may inform how you query that table
- What output am I expecting - what columns, how much data, what types?
- How frequently is the querying going to run?

**Design**

Map out your design on paper or a diagram, this is especially useful if you are working on a data warehouse with a [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)

Show what tables will be used and relationships between them.

**Comments**

Add something like this to the head of any stored procedure or function, or saved SQL code, and update it when you make changes to the code. This help you and others understand what the code is for and why changes have been made.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stored Procedure : usp_SSRS_ReportName                                               --
-- DateTime  : 07/07/2014                                                              --
-- Author    : John Smith                                                          --
-- Purpose   : Get Date for Report                              --
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Ver  |    Date    |  Author    | Description                                        --
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 1.00 | 07/07/2014 | J Smith | Created.                                          --
-- 1.10 | 10/02/2015 | B Builder | Split sales by currency, removed company param 
--                                                      --
```

Comment: Thank you @PeterCampbell.  This is helpful and I also appreciate the links, they are helpful as well.

Comment: To stay DRY, it is essential to work from the bottom up -- finish out building blocks and work up.  Pseudo-code lets you use comments that sketch the larger scheme.  I like this answer, so felt inspired to add to it.

Comment: Thanks @Smandoli.  I had never heard of the DRY concept before, so this is helpful and I appreciate your addition as well.